# Haskell printf to string

Tags: string, haskell

Is there a sprintf equivalent in Haskell?

I need to convert and format double values into strings.

Is there another way without using *printf* kind of functions?

The main problem is to avoid:

```
Prelude> putStrLn myDoubleVal
1.7944444444444447e-2
```

Instead, I want this:

```
Prelude> putStrLn . sprintf "%.2f" $ myDoubleVal
1.79
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes, it's in the [Text.Printf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/Text-Printf.html) module, and it's just called `printf`.

```
> import Text.Printf
> let x = 1.14907259
> putStrLn . printf "%.2f" $ x
1.15
```

Note that the return type of `printf` is overloaded, so that it's capable of returning a `String` (as in the example above) but it's also capable of returning an I/O action that does the printing, so you don't actually need the call to `putStrLn`:

```
> printf "%.2f\n" x
1.15
```

Comment: Checked, I didn't know it prints both IO and String with the same function.

Comment: @Zhen A type-safe version might be of interest: http://hpaste.org/79643 E.g. format (str."-".str."/".int) "Hello!" "World!" 123

Comment: There's also the [`show*Float`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Numeric.html) functions if you like a bit more type safety than what `printf` can give.

Comment: I think `show*Float` are great, but overkilling for me. In the real app I using it (print a CSV) its better to use printf.

Comment: Beginners like myself, note that `let x = 2 ; printf "%d\n" x` doesn't compile. Error "_Ambiguous type variable 'a0' arising from the literal '2'_". To fix that, use `let x = (2 :: Int)`.

Answer (score 3):

[Text.Printf](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/4.2.0.1/doc/html/Text-Printf.html) might be what you need.

Answer (score 0):

[Formatting](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/formatting) is an option to create formatted string, if you want '"s"printf' and don't need full compatibility with printf style.