# Print list of floats with format

Tags: haskell, printf

In Haskell, how can I print a list of floats (or `Fractional`, rather) and also specify formatting? E.g. `putStrLn $ magic "%.2f" [3.14159]` should print `[3.14]`.

As pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15566299/haskell-printf-to-string) there is `Text.Printf (printf)`, but I don't understand how to use it with lists?

One thing that 'works' is

```
printf' :: [Double] -> [String]
printf' l = map (\x -> printf "%.2f" x) l
```

with

```
main = do
  putStrLn $ show (printf' [3.14159])
```

but it's horrible, there must be another way.

The first two examples in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36659084/4743466) to a similar question don't work at all.

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36663707/4743466) is neat enough, but as pointed out is not type-safe, plus it breaks `Read`/`Show` interop.

Are there any other alternatives? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with "It's horrible".

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I'm not very familiar with all the lingo yet, but... lack of overloading? Without the specialization `[Double] -> [String]` it won't work. Ideally, I'd say, ghc would be able to infer that it's `Fractional a => [a] -> [String]`. Stuff like that.

Comment: `printf' = map (printf "%.2f")` is equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of [**`intercalate :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [a]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) to put commas between the elements, and do some additional list processing to add a `'['` in front and an `']'` at the end, like:

```
import Data.List(intercalate)

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn ('[' : intercalate "," (printf' [3.14159]) ++ "]")
```

this then yields:

```
Prelude Text.Printf Data.List> main
[3.14]
```

Note that you can simplify your `printf'` to just:

```
printf' :: [Double] -> [String]
printf' = map (printf "%.2f")
```

Answer (score 3):

You can import the Numeric library to achieve this. I've quickly written a small program as an example, without the use of the printf function.

```
module Main where

import Numeric

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "hello world"

a = [1.111, 2.2222222222222, 3.33333333333333333333333]

printList :: [Double] -> [String]
printList xs = map format xs

format :: Double -> String
format x = showFFloat (Just 2) x ""
```

where the simple call `printList a` will result in:

```
["1.11","2.22","3.33"]
```

Comment: Maybe I should just use `Numeric` after all. But, how is it that, in defining `format`, `shoFFloat` can take three arguments, when its signature says it takes only two?

Comment: @ErikVesterlund Its "return type", `ShowS`, is a type alias for a function type.

Comment: @ErikVesterlund It takes two arguments and it returns a `ShowS` which is a function `String -> String`, taking the third argument.

Comment: You can also choose how many digits you want to use. I hardcoded it to 2, since that satisfied your needs, but it is customizable. More on that [here](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=showFFloat) ,


I probably should've mentioned that in my answer too. Anyway, I never use Haskell without at least having 3 tabs of Hoogle available in the background too :)